# R Shiny App Error: "Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm fairly new to Shiny, but I attempting to create an app that allows a user to come in and type either a first name, last name, or social security number (or all three or two, etc.) and then it will ping a sql query and return the proper result. I am running into the following error however.

```
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
  [No stack trace available]
```

Below is my code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  
  textInput(inputId = "First_Name",
              label = "First_Name",
              value = "",
              width = NULL,
              placeholder = "Enter Client's First Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "SSN",
            label = "SSN",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's SSN"),
  textInput(inputId = "Last_Name",
            label = "Last_Name",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's Last Name"),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "300px")
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  BDW <- odbcConnect("BDW", uid="", pwd="", believeNRows = FALSE)
  
  table1 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste("
                      SELECT name as 'Name:',ssn as 'SSN', a.address + ', ' + a.city + ', ' + a.state + ', ' + a.zip as 'Address:'
  FROM [RM].[dbo].[CustomerMaster] a
    LEFT JOIN [UVC].[dbo].[UVCWeb_CustomerFlat]b ON a.number = b.RMNumber
  WHERE
  name like '%",input$First_Name,"%'
  and name like '%",input$Last_Name,"%'
  and ssn like '%",input$SSN,"%'
  and bdw_CurrentIndicator = 1"))})
  
  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    plot(table1()$Name, table1()$SSN, table1()$Address)
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data involved is pretty simple just a customers name, SSN, and address. Really appreciate all of the help up front. Thanks!

Comment: What should be your output? Currently you try to generate a plot with the first names as x - axis and the SSN on y - axis, and then the adress as what? Do you reallly want a plot or do you want a rendered text ?

Comment: @pbraeutigm I had no idea that’s what I was doing. I’m truly just trying to return a table. With the column headers being Name, SSN, and Address. It will eventually become a clickable table where the user selects one of the records and it takes them to another page.

Comment: You can "plot" your table with e.g. the datatable library.  You would edit your code with:

  dataTableOutput("mytable") in your ui and output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    your data.table
  }) in your server. see here:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! @pbraeutigm if you will post as answer I will accept! Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "plot" your table with e.g. the `library(datatable)`. You would edit your code with:

```
 dataTableOutput("mytable")
```

in your ui and

```
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({ your data.table })
```

in your server.
See here: shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.htm